# How to crack a bucket of walnuts quickly without compromising the taste?

Tags: nuts, food-processing

I read that you can accelerate the process of cracking walnuts by freezing them — the shells either crack all by themselves or are otherwise so brittle that they can be opened with one hand. However, this somehow ruins the edible parts too. Walnuts, thus extracted, are suitable only for cooking and roasting.

Is there a way to crack many walnuts simultaneously, without compromising the taste and texture? OK to compromise aesthetics of the product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the right tool your best bet.

I have best luck with key type plus a nut pick.
[image]

Or the spring type:
https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=IEzK8MVGa0s

For speed, hammer works great too and with some practice actually yields more than walnutbutter.